# C# - Choosing a Random Value From an Array with Spesific Range and Times

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I'm working on a fixture program which is at Console Application phase for now. I arranged the teams thanks to all of you :) but I can't organize the days that teams will play with each other. So I created an array named DaysReprep with 4 elements which they represents the days of the week.(i.e. 0 represents Monday,4 represents Friday,5 represents Saturday and 6 represents Sunday which teams can play match at these days.)I also created an array named dayCounts that holds how many times they created randomly. I want to choose them randomly but, when 0 chose randomly I don't want it to create randomly again. Like that, I want to generate randomly 1 for 3 times (not in a row.), 2 for 4 times (not in a row.) and 3 for 1 times.

Here’s my code and my output,
Any help would be appreciated.

```
        int[] daysReprep = new int[4] { 0, 4, 5, 6 };   //holds the representation of days(0-monday,4-friday,5-saturday,6-sunday)
        int RandomChosenDay; //random value 
        int[] dayCounters = new int[4]; //which counts which element of the daysReprep array generated by RandomChosenDay(0.element holds 0.element of daysReprep and goes so on.)

        for (int i = 0; i < weeklyMatched.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
              RandomChosenDay = randomNum.Next(3);

             switch (RandomChosenDay)
            {

                case 0:

                    if (dayCounters[0] != 1)
                    {
                        dayCounters[0]++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        RandomChosenDay = randomNum.Next(3);  
                    }
                      break;


                case 1:

                    if (dayCounters[1] != 3)
                    {
                        dayCounters[1]++;
                        break;
                    }

                    else {
                     RandomChosenDay=randomNum.Next(3);                  
                    }

                    break;

                 case 2:
                    if (dayCounters[2] != 4)
                    {
                        dayCounters[2]++;
                        break;
                    }

                    else {
                      RandomChosenDay = randomNum.Next(3);

                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (dayCounters[3] != 1)
                    {
                        dayCounters[3]++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
          RandomChosenDay = randomNum.Next(3);
                    }
               break;
            }

            for(int a = 0; a < daysReprep.Length; a++) //Writes the elemts of the dayCounters
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dayCounters[a] + " ");

            }
```

[image: My LeagueFixture Output]

Comment: In your `for` loop `weeklyMatched.GetLength(1)` is 7 so the `for` loop will do just 7 times. Total times you want is `1 + 4 + 4 + 1 = 10`.

Comment: The weeklyMatched.GetLength(1) equals to 9 from the start.But it still generates the same amount of numbers which is equal to 7.

Comment: `randomNum.Next(3);` never return 3. Try to change to `randomNum.Next(4);`